# A word to describe a place which is "very cozy"

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to ask for your help to describe a coffee shop that is very cozy for chatting.

Comment: What place are you referring to? A room, house, church, school, etc.? The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try **intimate**.

**Intimate**- characterized by or suggesting an atmosphere conducive to privacy or intimacy; warmly cozy

(dictionary.com)

The little coffee shop had a very **intimate** atmosphere, making it easy to conduct deep, personal conversations for hours on end.

You could also use **comfy**.

The **comfy** coffee shop was a great place to have private conversations.

Comment: Also, [snug] (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snug). As in, *We enjoyed New Year's eve in the snug coffee shop across the street*.

Comment: Somewhere like a coffee shop could be cosy without being comfy. A warm (literally and figuratively) atmosphere but hard chairs facing each other over tiny tables would be one example.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for some formal school project or an essay, I would go with `intimate` or `snug` and avoid `comfy` as it is informal. Otherwise, it is all good.

Answer (score 0):

**Homey**, **homely**,  **snug**, or **commodious** are words that can be used, in addition to comfy and intimate.

Comment: 'Homely' means ugly in AmE, so don't use that in the US.